# Java Insert multi row data from file.txt to table of database

Tags: java, postgresql, filereader, java-io

I have a text file consisting of several lines. 
I want to add the whole lines to the table of database.
Before it is inserted to table, it should be `substring` to get fields value of database table.  I think my code (Query) is not good for big data. I know there is other way to do that condition.

```
public class ReaderFilesData {
    LinkedList<String> listFiles = new LinkedList<String>();
    private Path path = Paths.get("src/FilesDownloaded/");
    DataTRX dataTRX = new DataTRX();

    public void readFiles() {
        File[] listFile = new File(path.toString()).listFiles();
        for (File file : listFile) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                listFiles.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total Files : " +listFiles.size());
    }

    public void readData() {
        Path pathsourceFile;

        String line;
        BufferedReader reader;
        for (int i=0; i<listFiles.size(); i++) {
            try {
                String fileName = listFiles.get(i);
                System.out.println("FileName : " +fileName);
                pathsourceFile = Paths.get("src/FilesDownloaded/"+fileName+"");
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathsourceFile.toString());
                while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
                    int startPoint = line.lastIndexOf(';')+1;
                    String valueLine = new String(line.substring(startPoint));
                    System.out.println("Transaction data : " +valueLine);
                    dataTRX.setId(valueLine.substring(0,2));
                    dataTRX.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(valueLine.substring(2, 10)));
                    dataTRX.setDesc(valueLine.substring(10, 18));

                    System.out.println("getId      : " + dataTRX.getId());
                    System.out.println("getAmount       : " + dataTRX.getAmount());
                    System.out.println("getDesc   : " + dataTRX.getDesc());

                    importData(dataTRX.getId(), 
                                dataTRX.getAmount(),
                                dataTRX.getDesc(),

                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    public void importData(String id, int amount, String discount ) {

    String insertData = "INSERT INTO tbl_trx (id, amount, desc) "
        + "VALUES (?,?,?)";

    try {
        try (PreparedStatement ps = GeneralRules.conn.prepareStatement(insertData)) {

            ps.setString(1, id);
            ps.setInt(2, amount);
            ps.setString(4, desc);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Data successfully update to database!!!\n");
            ps.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

This is example data of file.txt

> - 320000000200000001
> - 2G0000000500000002
> - AB0000001500000001

I do substring data base on line above :

> - substring id,amount,discount (32,00000002,00000001)
> - substring id,amount,discount (2G,00000005,00000002)
> - substring id,amount,discount (AB,00000015,00000001)

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions so you will be better prepared and able to ask a question that will be well received and more importantly **answerable**.

Comment: **Primarily Opinion Based** - *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions making it **Too Broad** as well automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good to me. But If I would have written it, below optimization/replacement, I would have done

1) Use `List` instead of `LinkedList` in variable declaration and remove generic `String` from reference point. Something like

`List<String> listFiles = new LinkedList<>();`

[Link for more explanation on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-preferred)

2) Similar to using try with resource you did for `PreparedStatement`, I would do the same for `BufferedReader`. This would remove the need to close the `BufferedReader' in the end

`try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathsourceFile.toString())))`

[Link for more explanation on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516020/try-with-resources-vs-try-catch)

3) Because you have used try with resource for `PreparedStatement`, there is no need to have `ps.close()`, because preparedstatement implements `AutoCloseable`. So try with resouce will take care of it

4) Instead of `e.getMessage()`, I would have used `e.printStackTrace()` because it would give me more information about the error

As far as your use of sub-string is concerned, I would have used it, or would have use regex to split the string.

If number of rows to be inserted are more, which I think is your case, instead of  calling `executeUpdate()` everytime, go with `Batch` mode. i.e add statements to `PreparedStatement` batch using `addBatch()` and execute in one go with `executeBatch()`

Comment: Oke thanks for your sugestion, but is this posible if I use that  insert query for thousands of data.? and how about ps.executeBatch(); ?

Comment: If number of records are huge, go with batch mode of `PreparedStatement`. Use `ps.addBatch();` and `prepStmt.executeBatch()` to execute more number of records.