# try-with-resource vs ordinary code with explicit close()-call

Tags: java

I have a `connection`-object which implements `java.io.Closeable` and I make use of try-with-resource:

**version 1:**

```
public List<User> findUsers(Query query) {
    try (this.connection) {
        return conn.find(query);
    }
    // no catch block defined
}
```

All works, however I am wondering **what is the difference in terms of behaviour** (for example, exceptions,..) between version 1 and 2:

**version 2:**

```
public List<User> findUsers(Query query) {
     var users = this.connection.find(query);
     this.connection.close();
     return users;
}
```

Comment: where is the exception handling code in version 2?

Comment: I does not handle any exception.

Comment: that's the point

Comment: The difference is that version 2 needs exception handling, and it's a lot of unnecessary boilerplate code

Comment: If an exception is thrown by `find(query)` in version 2, `close()` will not be called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Try With Resources vs Try-Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516020/try-with-resources-vs-try-catch)

Comment: @jhamon yes, thanks, so I will use **version 1**.

Comment: I changed the **version 1** by using `try(this.connection)` instead of `try(var conn = this.connection)`. I think, it's the same.

Comment: The difference is that the 2nd version does not have a try... catch (as in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516020/try-with-resources-vs-try-catch)) therefore there is no grantee the close will happen.